# Dropdownlist validation not working

Tags: php, html, validation

I've try several times for dropdownlist validation, 
my codes are in PHP and HTML, the the validation part is not working though and i've refer some of the solutions in stackoverflow which has similar case like mine.

Declare variable

```
$call_department = $db->escape((int)$_POST['call_department']); //where i declare this variable
```

---

HTML files

```
<tr><td>Department</td><td><select name='call_department'>
<option></option>
<?php $call_dept = $db->get_results("select type_id,type_name from site_types where type=1 order by type_name;");
foreach ($call_dept as $dept )
{?>
<option value='<?php echo $dept->type_id;?>'><?php echo $dept->type_name; required?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select></td></tr>
```

---

Validation part:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['call_department']) && $_REQUEST['call_department'] == '0') { 
echo 'Please select a department.'; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: set first option value=0 like this <option value="0">select</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Set first option `value="0"` like this

```
<option value="0">select</option>
```

2) `Required` attribute should be set to select tag not to option tag `<select name='call_department' required>`

```
<select name='call_department' required>
<option value="0">select</option>
<?php $call_dept = $db->get_results("select type_id,type_name from site_types where type=1 order by type_name;");
foreach ($call_dept as $dept )
{
?>
<option value='<?php echo $dept->type_id;?>'><?php echo $dept->type_name; ?></option>

<?php } ?>
</select>
```